# How can I type the +- symbol in R

Tags: r, symbols

I need to use a heading that includes Mean +- SD. So far, I can only get this:

```
"Mean +- SD or N (%)"
[1] "Mean +- SD or N (%)"
```

How can I directly use the "+-" symbol? You know the one character, not two.

Just for the future, how about other symbols, like Greek letter and so on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you're going to be putting these on a plot. If that's the case, then be sure to check out the `?plotmath` help page. In your example, you could use

```
plot(1,1,main=expression(paste("Mean", phantom(.)%+-%phantom(.), "SD or N (%)")))
```

If you're just taking about plain text output, that depends on the encoding you have set up on your GUI. And how you type that in would depend on your operating system. You can include the unicode escape code in a string

```
x<-"Mean \u00b1 SD or N (%)"
Encoding(x)<-"UTF-8"
x
#[1] "Mean ± SD or N (%)"
```

Comment: I am not putting it in a plot; I am putting it in a table. So the second solution is the one I wanted. But how do you know what magic combination of characters and numbers to use, e.g. "\u00b1"? Is there a place I can look it up? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your OS and default encoding. Here I used unicode but that symbol appears in other encodings as well.

Comment: It's actually less about encoding and more about what fonts are being used on the graphical device. Just because it appears on the console in a particular way doesn't always mean it will appear on a pdf or png output.

Comment: I also find plotmath paste() to be kind of 'ugly' and prefer pure expressions when they are possible: `main=expression(Mean %+-% SD~or~N~"(%)")`

Comment: Here it is. Copy this in a text file somewhere, use it (copy-paste) whenever needed! ±

Comment: Hi BondedDust, you are right. It looked good in the console but became  non-sense after I output it using "write.csv". Do you know how to fix it?